# Создание папки программным способом Android

Tags: java, android

Пишу для курсовой работы примитивный файловый менеджер. Хочу создать кнопку которая будет создавать новую папку. Как это можно реализовать? В этом я чайник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру так:

```
private File create(String name) {
    File baseDir;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    } else {
        baseDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    }

    if (baseDir == null)
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File folder = new File(baseDir, name);

    if (folder.exists()) {
        return folder;
    }
    if (folder.isFile()) {
        folder.delete();
    }
    if (folder.mkdirs()) {
        return folder;
    }

    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}
```

Метод делает следующее: Если папка с именем `name` не существует, то она создастся в директории Downloads, иначе ничего не делать.